# Opposite meaning

Tags: vocabulary, exam-questions

Choose the closest opposite meaning : She is indeed ***human***.

a) universal
b) devilish 
c) divine
d) terrestrial

I'm confused between "devilish" and "divine". Can anyone tell me what is right one?

Comment: As a native English speaker, that question is very unclear. I'd guess divine, but I'm not sure. Also, welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: @米凯乐 I to am a native BrE speaker and agree that the question is somewhat unclear, although logically the answer is **divine** by elimination as Jeff Morrow says in  his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately eliminate "universal" and "terrestrial." Neither is particularly pertinent to the state of being human or not human.

"Devilish" means being similar to a devil, but is frequently applied to humans.

> That woman has a devilish grin.

Moreover, it usually has an implication of naughtiness rather than evil. No one skilled in English would write

> Hitler was quite devilish when he ordered the construction of the death camps.

Thus, the best fit is **divine**, but it is not a synonym for "non-human."